# How to set distance of Freestyle line rendering?

Tags: freestyle

I would like to have thicker lines near camera and a lot of thinner in some range of distance from camera.

How can I achive this?

I tried 'Distance from camera' modifier (I tested all settings. Including "Invert" checkbox) and the only results I'm getting is the opposit effect: thicker lines far from camera and thinner near camera.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Distance modifier scope is to control the line's thickness with its distance from camera. The main parameters are four:

- **Range Min**: the distance of the camera's nearest object from the camera itself
- **Range Max**: the distance of the camera's fartest object from the camera itself
- **Value Min**: the bottom value of the graph
- **Value Max**: the top value of the graph

[image]

*The values*

Notice that I'm talking about the graph and not the resulting thickness (that is the curve itself) because I would like to suggest that is **not a good idea** to set a Max value **lower** than the Min value.

The values should be defined in order **to set up the graph** (if you choose Linear insead of Curve you are just forcing the curve to be straight, but the concept is the same), then you can tweak the curve to get the desired result.

*The range*

To quickly get the correct **Range Min**&**Max** value you can use the built-in function **Fill range by selection.** Basilcally you'll just have to pick two object, push the button and you'll automatically have the fields filled up.

[image]

Once the four parameters are set up, you can focus on defining the curve. In your case you should draw a top to down strahight curve to get higher values at the beginning of the range and lower at its the end as shown in the image above.

---

If you would like to use the Linear option, you should activate the invert option in order to flip the straight curve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Conclusions:**

Start from filling the four parametrs with appropriate values.

In your case you left the default Range parameters (0-1000). I can't see the scale of your model, but I can guess that they are not appropriate. Give it a check.

Start from using very different Min Max values (e.g 1-50) to see the effect clearly and then lower them once you are sure that all works...

...and make sure the modifier is **ENABLED FOR RENDER** or you'll not see any of its cool effects! :)

[image]